# .NET Application Access Permission

Tags: c#, networking

I am implementing an application in C#. I am trying to find a way so that if this application is running outside my company it will not run and if it is inside it will run.

```
if(ValidateRunInsideCompanyNetwork())
   {

       RunApplication();
   }
 else 
   { 
       MessageBox("You're outside the company. You're not authorized to run app.");
   }
```

We can access the domain remotely while working from home. I don't have even idea how this is done.  Is there a way for that? Some people try to access a server inside the network and if it is accessible that's mean he is inside. Any other better approaches?

Comment: did any of this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Do note, this is a weak form of protection.

But you have a couple of options.

First of all: working from home can be accomplished through a `VPN`. It's even possible to distinguish between

- inside office network
- inside office VPN
- every thing else

Your application can obviously test whether or not it's connected to the domain (example will follow later). It can use certificates, host availability, etc. But this is still a weak form of protection.

Your protection level would increase significant if your local application is only a shell around data and the data used by the application is retrieved through API's. This way you don't need to store essential data locally, and keep it remote, "safely" out of malicious hands.